# How to convert PySpark Pandas Dataframe to a PySpark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset stored into a `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` which I want to convert to a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` before saving it to a delta file. Which is the right way to do it?

P.S: The reason for this is because I want to enforce a schema-on-write when saving it to delta. However, PySpark Panda's `to_delta` method seems not to accept schema parameters .

Thanks in advance

Comment: does this help? https://docs.databricks.com/pandas/pyspark-pandas-conversion.html

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. When passing a PySpark Pandas dataframe, it complains about requiring a schema, and after providing it, it complains about `not accept object`.

Comment: how about `pypandas_df.to_spark()`?  still same error?

Comment: Actually it worked! Completely overlooked it! Thanks!